# Problem with how Bibliography appears

Tags: bibliographystyle

I have a `Bibliography.bib` file with the following code:

```
@online{Bacterial_Classification,
  author   = "Franklin D. Lowy",
  title    = "Bacterial Classification, Structure and Function",
  url      = "https://api.semanticscholar.org/CorpusID:49963607",
  year     = 2008,
  note     = "Accessed: Columbia University",
  keywords = "Basics of Bacteria"
}

@article{Mass_Spectrometry,
  author =       "Anja Freiwald
and Sascha Sauer",
  title =        "Phylogenetic classification and identification of bacteria by mass spectrometry",
  journal =      "Nat Protoc",
  volume =       "4",
  number =       "5",
  pages =        "732-742",
  year =         "2009, doi: https://doi.org/10.1038/nprot.2009.37",
  DOI =          "https://doi.org/10.1038/nprot.2009.37",
  keywords =     "Spectrometry"
}
```

I have my `main.tex` file with the following:

```
\documentclass[twoside, a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2}
 
\usepackage[top=2.5cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, headheight=1.25cm, footskip=1.25cm, margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{name=Figure}
\captionsetup[table]{name=Table}
\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\justifying

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{esint}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{minted}

\setlength{\parindent}{0em}

\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}{Chapter~\thesection :}{1em}{}

\usepackage{cite} 
\usepackage{xurl}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=black,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,      
    urlcolor=black,
    pdftitle={Comparative Study of Electronic Circuits for Bacterial Identification},
    pdfauthor={Dimitrios D. Koliouskas},
    pdfpagemode=FullScreen,
    }
\urlstyle{same}



\begin{document}

\section{Example}
\input{Chapter 1}
\clearpage

\pagestyle{plain}
\nocite{*}

\renewcommand{\refname}{REFERENCES}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{REFERENCES}
\bibliography{Bibliography}
\clearpage

\end{document}
```

I also have a `Chapter 1.tex` file with the following example code:

```
\subsection{Also an example}
Typing...
\cite{Bacterial_Classification}

\subsubsection{example no.2}
Typing...
\cite{Mass_Spectrometry}
```

With `THIS` specific example in a new blank project it works as it should. `BUT` in my real document it does not work and my 2nd cited paper (`Mass_Spectrometry`) appears first in references, with the number `[1]`, instead of second, although I mentioned first the `Bacterial_Identification`. I must clarify that in my real document I really do not have anything else from packages to anything. Literally the only thing that changes is the text in the document and the number of `.tex` files. I really do not know where the problem is.

I `JUST` figured that any bibliography that I cite in the following will go first in references (This is an edit and I did not include the packages for figures/tables in my `main.tex`):

```
\begin{figure}[hbt]
\center
\resizebox{1\textwidth}{!}{\includegraphics{A bacterial sample to a protein extraction and the final analysis by mass spectrometry.jpg}}
\caption{A bacterial sample subjected to a protein extraction and the final analysis by mass spectrometry. \cite{Mass_Spectrometry}}
  \label{Fig:Mass Spectrometry}
\end{figure}
```

why is this happening? The funny thing is that the `\cite{Bacterial_Classification}` is mentioned 4 times before the above figure (1 inside the text and 3 in 3 different figures, all before the above-mentioned figure).

Comment: The first mentioning is in the list of figures. Use `\caption[text without cite for the list of figures]{text with cite}`

Comment: There is no point in posting dozens of lines of code that no one can use as it includes files we don't have, make a small self contained example removing all packages not needed in the example. For example including `minted` means you need `--shell-escape` and I would not use `--shell-escape ` on a document copied from the internet

Comment: in your figure, never use `\center` that is part of the implementation of teh `center` environment, the command form is `\centering`  and don't use `\resizebox` simply use `width=`  key on the `\includegraphics`, wow, you really use file names like `A bacterial sample to a protein extraction and the final analysis by mass spectrometry.jpg`  It should work in recent latex but using spaces is brave and I'm not sure I've ever seen a filename with that many spaces:-)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That was it!! Thank you very much!! So simple solutions, I am feeling bad now for not noticing myself...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you too for your observations and corrections! You have to excuse me, I do not know how things work yet. As for your second comment, so instead of writing \center I should write always \centering? Also file names should have _ perhaps instead of spaces? I did not know it, I will correct it. Folders too or only files?

Comment: @DGuys spaces are a problem because on the commandline to (say) move a file you need `mv two word.jpeg new name.jpg`  which fails as the spaces separate the arguments, so you need `mv 'two word.jpeg' 'new name.jpg'` but that means when generating such commands in strings you have to be _really_ careful with losing quotes (eg if `'` is used to delimit the whole string) and things can easily go wrong.  people used to GUI interfaces naturally use more spaces as those of us more used to command lines hardly ever do as even creating a file with a space in its name is more work than  you want to do

Comment: what is the difference between \centering and \Centering?

Comment: @DGuys - The former command is provided by the LaTeX kernel, whereas the latter is provided by the [ragged2e](https://ctan.org/pkg/ragged2e) package. Please read the user guide of the `ragged2e` package to learn about the differences between the two commands.