# Cite references ( \cite{} ) in Tables/Figures

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, floats, captions, citing

I have the following table:

```
\begin{table}[hbt]
\centering
\tabcolsep=0.3cm
\caption{Gram Negative Bacteria.}{\cite{Bacterial_Classification}}
\label{Tab:Gram Negative Bacteria}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\small
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ p{5em} >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X p{5em} p{5em} >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X }
    \toprule
    \textbf{Name} & \textbf{Morphology} & \textbf{O\textsubscript{2} Require\-ments} & \textbf{Commensal} & \textbf{Reservoirs / Sites \-of colonization, Transmission} & \textbf{Types of Infections} \\ \midrule
    Entero\-bacteriaceae (E. coli, klebsiella, salmonella, shigella) & Rods & facultative anaerobe & Some species & GI tract, animals / Endogenous, fecal oral & Diarrhea, uninary tract, food poisoning, sepsis \\
    Bacteroides & Rods & anaerobic & Yes & GI tract / Endogenous & Abscesses \\
    Pseudomonas & Rods & aerobic & No & Water, soil / Endogenous, breach of skin barrier & Infections in immunocompromised hosts, Cystic Fibrosis \\
    Vibrio (cholera) & Rods, curved shap & micro\-aerophilic & No & Water / Contaminated food, water & Diarrhea \\
    Campylobac\-ter & Rods, curved shape & micro\-aerophilic & No & Food / Ingestion of contaminated food & Diarrhea, Bacteremia \\
    Legionella & Rods, poorly stained & micro\-aerophilic & No & Water Inhalation of aerosol & Pneumonia, febrile illness \\
    Neisseriam & Cocci, kidney-bean shaped & Micro\-aerophilic & No (\textit{N. meningitidis} sometimes) & Humans / Sexual, aerosol & Meningitis, pelvic inflammatory disease \\
    Hemophilus & Coccobacillary-pleomorphic & facultative anaerobe & Some species & Respiratory tract / Endogenous, aerosol & Respiratory, sinusitis, otitis, meningitis \\
    Bartonella & Small, pleomorphic rods & aerobic/micro\-aerophilic & No & Cats, fleas, lice / cat bites, lice or fleas? & Cat scratch disease, endocarditis, bacillary angiomatosis \\\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

I also have the following figure:

```
\begin{figure}[hbt]
\centering
\resizebox{1\textwidth}{!}{\includegraphics{Thesis/Images/Chapters/Chapter 1/A_bacterial_sample_to_a_protein_extraction_and_the_final_analysis_by_mass_spectrometry.jpg}}
\caption{A bacterial sample subjected to a protein extraction and the final analysis by mass spectrometry.}{\cite{Mass_Spectrometry}}
  \label{Fig:Mass Spectrometry}
\end{figure}
```

These 2 represent the same example I want you to focus. The citation is appearing under the table or figure caption and not in the end of the text of table/figure caption.

If I cite like this:  `\caption{A bacterial sample subjected to a protein extraction and the final analysis by mass spectrometry. \cite{Mass_Spectrometry}}` we will end up with a problem in referencing order cause the list of figures. So we must keep the form `\caption{A bacterial sample subjected to a protein extraction and the final analysis by mass spectrometry.}{\cite{Mass_Spectrometry}}`. This is also the correct way to do it: `\caption[text without cite for the list of figures]{text with cite}`

P.S. I do not include the packages used in preamable because I assume they do not matter for this problem. If you want it, just comment it and I will edit.

Comment: `\caption` only has one mandatory argument, I assume you meant `\caption[Gram Negative Bacteria.]{\cite{Bacterial_Classification}}` not `\caption{Gram Negative Bacteria.}{\cite{Bacterial_Classification}}`

Comment: "P.S. I do not include the packages used in preamable because I assume they do not matter for this problem. " it _always_ helps to provide an example that shows the problem. No one can run these fragments. Don't include all the packages from your real document but make a small complete document that shows the problem.

Comment: `\resizebox{1\textwidth}{!}{\includegraphics{...}}` sounds like a very complicated way to say `\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{...}`

Comment: seing as the question is about captions you could also change the text of the figure (to say`ABC`  as currently people need to guess at least `booktabs`, `tabularx` and `graphicx` packages to run these fragments

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz [a very wise person made the same comment yesterday](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/702603/problem-with-how-bibliography-appears#comment1747764_702603)

Comment: You both are correct, I hope every time I post from now on to have a better appearance and more clear informations. @DavidCarlisle As for your first comment... I did meant \caption[text]{\cite{}}, BUT as I see I do not write such a thing.. Is this the mistake causing the problem? I will chek in a minute.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I see, I'm so slow :)

Answer (score 3):

`\caption` only has one mandatory argument, I assume you meant

`\caption[Gram Negative Bacteria.]{\cite{Bacterial_Classification}}`

not

`\caption{Gram Negative Bacteria.}{\cite{Bacterial_Classification}}`

Comment: Correct! Once again, you save the day from silly mistakes.

Comment: +1. I think it would be helpful to include some text in the main argument of `\caption` as well. Thus, `\caption[Gram Negative Bacteria.]{Gram Negative Bacteria \cite{Bacterial_Classification}.}`.

Comment: @Mico Thank you, I agree! I did it myselft. In order for it to appear in the list of figures too.

Comment: In a long table, how could this be fixed? Because there we have this: caption = {Gram Positive Bacteria.}{\cite{Bacterial_Classification}} and it does not fix if I but [] instead of {}.

Comment: Everything works fine in the caption but the cite appears in the list of figures too.

Comment: @DGuys no it won't that is the point of using `[...]` a version without cite for the list. You have probably not re-run latex.

Comment: If I run this: `\begin{longtblr}[
caption = [Gram Positive Bacteria.]{Gram Positive Bacteria.\cite{Bacterial_Classification}}`, it will appear: `Table 1.1: [Gram Positive Bacteria.]Gram Positive Bacteria. [1]`

Comment: both in caption and in the list of figures.

Comment: It works with normal tables but not with a longtable.

Comment: You could (should?) have mentioned earlier that you employ a `longtblr` environment.

Comment: it works with `longtable` . You are not using `longtable` but `longtblr` from a different package you have not mentioned. @DGuys

Comment: @DGuys check the tabularray documentation, it probably has a key to specify the list of tables entry, just as it has a key to specify the caption

Comment: I opened the documentation but I can not find it. Could you possibly help me a bit more with this?

Comment: @DGuys no sorry it's completely unrelated to the question as posted, and not a package I know that well.